# Mongoid YAML Configuration

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, yaml

In my YML file for Mongo, it fails on the below:

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: library
      username: lib_user
      password: <%= ENV['MONGO_PASSWORD'] %>
      hosts:
        - <%= ENV['MONGO_HOST'] %>:<%= ENV['MONGO_PORT'] %>
```

The last line in particular is where the error occurs. The error is below.

```
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 26 column 11
```

If I remove the environment variable for the port, everything works fine. What syntax issue am I missing here?

Comment: What exactly is in `MONGO_HOST` and `MONGO_PORT`? Any stray spaces getting in anywhere?

Comment: @muistooshort So turns out if I get rid of the space after the '-' it works. Also, I wasn't even using this environment. It was throwing a syntax error on the YML compile. MONGO_HOST and MONGO_PORT were null.

Comment: So you ended up with `- :` pretending to be YAML and it was trying to interpret that colon as YAML syntax rather than a string?

Comment: @muistooshort Not sure how that ended up, but I do know that this goes fine without the syntax error:
'-<%= ENV['MONGO_HOST'] %>:<%= ENV['MONGO_PORT'] %>'
So maybe it was coming back as '- :' Where the null was a space and somehow '-:' works?

Comment: What does `<%= ... %>` do to convert the expression to a string? Call `to_s` perhaps? And `nil.to_s == ''` so...

Comment: @muistooshort That looks like the likely explanation. My guess is that space after the dash is unnecessary, but two spaces throws an error. so '-s:s' is fine but '-ss:s' is not. (s for space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the YAML in that file, although I kind of would have expected a space after the colon in the last line (so that the value for `hosts` is a list of one key-value pair, instead of the list of a string).

Psych however is complaining about the expansion it tries to do on scalars it read in from YAML and `<%= ENV['MONGO_HOST'] %>` will throw that error if `MONGO_HOST` is not defined in the environment. If you try and set that, the YAML file should load (or maybe complain about line 26 column 36 if `MONGO_PORT` is not defined either).

Comment: I don't have to define Mongo_Host if I remove the space after the dash.

Comment: @steventnorris If you do that you get a scalar string starting with `-<%=...` instead of a list with a single scalar string starting `<%=...`. Mongoid probably just walks over the single characters in the former case, never finding the pattern to replace.

Comment: So, I run this in multiple environments. In a local environment MONGO_HOST is not defined. How do I format this so that it will not throw a error in that case? I've done this with ActiveRecord and Postgres using YML. Mongoid and MongoDB should have the same capability I assume.

Comment: Marking this correct, but wanted to note that using a ternary to put either a random, failing login or the ENV variable was the working solution.